# How to use uglifyjs 3 mangle option with toplevel and reserverd?

Tags: uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I have the below command:

```
uglifyjs  main.js bar.js  -m  toplevel reserved=['$','addTo','exports']   -c --source-map -o out.js
```

But it throws error:

```
ERROR: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'reserved=[$,addTo,exports]'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
```

How can I use both options toplevel (mangle function names) and reserved under -m option?
I am using latest uglifyJs and node 8.6 .

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
uglifyjs -m reserved=['$','addTo','exports'] toplevel=true  -c --source-map -o out.js -- main.js bar.js
```

Comment: yesshashah this does not work I still get the same error

Comment: @ace how about if you add input files to the end: `uglifyjs -m reserved=['$','addTo','exports'] toplevel=true -c --source-map -o out.js -- main.js bar.js
`

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer is:

> uglifyjs  main.js bar.js  -m 
>   toplevel,reserved=['$','addTo','exports']   -c --source-map -o out.js

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try not using command line,
this works for me in the latest version of uglify-JS 3

```js
var fs = require("fs");

var UglifyJs = require('uglify-js');

let data = fs.readFileSync('main.js','utf8')

let options = {
    sourceMap:{
        filename:"out.js",
        url:"out.js.map"
    },
    mangle:{
        reserved:["addTo","exports"],
        toplevel:true,
    }
};

var result = UglifyJs.minify(data,options)
console.log(result.code)
console.log(result.map)
fs.writeFile("out.js",result.code,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("File was successfully saved")
    }
})
fs.writeFile("out.js.map",result.map,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("File was successfully saved")
    }
})
```